# How to regenerate /var/cache/debconf on Debian?

Tags: debian, debconf

Suppose one deleted (or damaged) the following files/folder.

```
/var/cache/debconf
/var/cache/debconf/config.dat
/var/cache/debconf/config.dat-old
/var/cache/debconf/passwords.dat
/var/cache/debconf/templates.dat
/var/cache/debconf/templates.dat-old
```

How to regenerate them?

Comment: I guess this is a good site to recover a deleted files: http://www.howtoforge.com/data_recovery_from_accidentally_deleted_files_or_crashed_drives_in_redhat_centos_and_fedora_linux

Comment: Consider it wiped. It is asked in context of [Verifiable Builds](https://www.whonix.org/wiki/Verifiable_Builds).

Answer (score 1):

The contents of this directory should be automatically regenerated as long as the directory exists. I just tried this on an Ubuntu VM. I first deleted the directory with `sudo rm -r /var/cache/debconf`, then I created a new directory with `sudo mkdir /var/cache/debconf`.

`apt-get` and `aptitude` seem to both work fine after this, and the directory is populated with new files.

As always, it is a good idea to make a backup or copy before doing things like this.

Edit:

Perhaps [this](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1823695) can help you.

Comment: It's regenerated, but then you run into many issues. Example: when you run `sudo dpkg-reconfigure console-data`, select `select keymap from archlist` then it says `Looking for keymap to install: 
NONE`. And more.

Comment: Oh, that is strange. I have no problems after recreating the debconf directory. I found a post on the Ubuntu forums (I tried searching for both Debian and Ubuntu), perhaps this can help you: http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1823695